# Shall we have a Community Promotion Ad in CrossValidated?

Tags: discussion, cross-validated

There is the Community Promotion Ads selection going on in Cross Validated. Link: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/community-promotion-ads-2016

[Stephen's message in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30560936#30560936)

Selected ads would be posted in the side bar on CV.

As DataScience is very closely related to statistics, I think it would be a good idea for us to have an ad there, which can improve our site, and also helps users discover our site easily.

**So, shall we do it or not?(If Yes, please upvote this post)  Would be great if  someone can propose a good tagline and a picture for the ad.**